# How To Track A Production error regarding System.Web.UI.PageTheme.SetStyleSheet() error

Tags: asp.net, webforms

My production asp.net 4.0 server (running in debug mode) is throwing lots of these errors and I can't figure out a way to track it down.  I've search for all my ***head*** tags and they all seem to have ***runat="server"*** in them.  My stacktrace is below and does not tell me the aspx page.  It's a web project, sadly, though not sure that matters.

I've tried to get these errors on my development system with no success.  I'm throwing lots on my server.

```
Using themed css files requires a header control on the page. (e.g. <head runat="server" />).

at System.Web.UI.PageTheme.SetStyleSheet() 
at System.Web.UI.Page.OnInit(EventArgs e) 
at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) 
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Comment: Where are you setting the theme?  Is it possible that your web.config in production is missing the theme settings from your debug web.config?

Comment: The theme is set in two places that I know of. I have a base page class with code like this:  Page.Theme = String.Format("Gray{0}", Utils.GetCurrentCodeCampYearStartDate().Year); and I have it set in the web.config like this:    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" styleSheetTheme="Gray2012" clientIDMode="AutoID">